# MongoDB Filter.In finds only first record

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to find records from mongodb using `In` filter. The collection has `unitId` stored as string and i want to find all documents with matching unitIds

```
    var ids = '1,2,3,4,5'.Split(',');
    var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.In("unitId",ids);

        await _engrafaim
            .Find(filter)
            .ForEachAsync((doc) =>
            {

                // this gets executed only once for the first id

                // do some work here

            }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The code above only find first matching id.

**Update1**

This did not work either. The result always contains one document.

```
     var ids = '1,2,3,4,5'.Split(',');
     var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.In("unitId",ids);
     var result = await _engrafaim
            .Find(filter)
            .ToListAsync()
             .ConfigureAwait(false);

            foreach (var doc in result)
            {
                // do some work
            }
```

Comment: first fetch all matching documents and convert them to a AsyncList using wait _engrafaim
            .Find(filter).ToListAsync() and then on the docs list perform .ForEach(///////////)

Comment: That did not work. The `in` filter always returns one document only

Comment: It is worth checking your actual data. Make sure your field is named unitId, remember MongoDb queries are case sensitive. Have you tried running the $in from MongoDb itself?